# Understanding order of multiple arguments being passed into resolve, and the value given to .then()

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
function fn() {
  return Promise.resolve("firstValue")
}

function twoReturnValues(firstValue) {
  return firstValue, "secondValue"
}

function twoReturnValuesPromise(firstValue) {
  return Promise.resolve(firstValue, "secondValue")
}

fn().then(twoReturnValues).then(console.log) // secondValue
fn().then(twoReturnValuesPromise).then(console.log) // firstValue
```

Given the code snippet above, I am confused why:

`fn().then(twoReturnValues).then(console.log)`

prints:
`secondValue`

and:
`fn().then(twoReturnValuesPromise).then(console.log)`

print: 
`firstValue`

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot have two return values, only one, and `"a", "b"` won't do what you think it does at that point. (If you need to return more complex data than a single value, return an array or an object instead.)

You are seeing two different behaviors.

**First:**

```js
return "a", "b"
```

This is using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator (`,`) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So, the expression `"a", "b"` evaluates to `"b"`, making your statement essentially the same as this:

```js
return "b"
```

**Second:**

```js
Promise.resolve("a", "b")
```

According to the [`Promise.resolve` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), it takes *one* parameter, the value to resolve the promise with. As it is usually the case in JavaScript, additional parameters are silently ignored, so you do essentially the same as here:

```js
Promise.resolve("a")
```